# fritz.box faulty hostname resolution after (presumably) dhcp renew

Tags: networking, macos, dns, dhcp, fritzbox

I have a macOS 10.13.6 client connected to Fritz!BOX running Fritz!OS 06.83

Suddenly, an application using TCP stopped working, and I traced down the cause to this:

```
$ hostname
myself.fritz.box
```

the machine is not reachable by its hostname:

```
$ ping myself.fritz.box
PING myself.fritz.box (192.168.178.38): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
^C
```

`nslookup` reveals that machine's hostname resolves  to two addresses:

```
$ nslookup myself.fritz.box fritz.box
Server:     fritz.box
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Name:   myself.fritz.box
Address: 192.168.178.38
Name:   myself.fritz.box
Address: 192.168.178.53
```

the other address works:

```
$ ping 192.168.178.53
PING 192.168.178.53 (192.168.178.53): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.178.53: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.178.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
^C
```

which indeed is the current address of the network adapter:

```
$ ifconfig en0
...
    inet 192.168.178.53 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.178.255
...
```

Any guesses of why this happens? This stays consistent also after rebooting the Fritz!BOX.

Comment: I'm in you same situation. Do you mind adding a tip on how you managed to resolve?
Did you change something in the Fritz!Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

（myself.fritz.box->192.168.178.38）This record may have been stored in the cache. When you use the ping command, you will get the records in the cache first. So you need to clear the cache.

Nslookup does not use cache, it starts name resolution from the DNS server. It seems that you are not enabling dynamic updates for DNS. So there are two such records in the DNS server.

Aging and Scavenging and dynamic updates are two important features of DNS. So I strongly recommend that you enable them which will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by going to the network settings of the FritzBox Router. There were two entries for the same hostname. I removed the outdated one and everything worked again.